# Удалить  Id , ContentResolver ???

Tags: cursor, android, cursoradaper, база-данных

пытаюсь удалить из database id ...Как написать Правильно Код ??

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        Log.d(TAG, "long item select");
        Log.d(TAG, "1");

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Favorite2:

            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
           long id = info.id;
        //  dbHandler.delete(id);
          Cursor cursor3 = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    Contract.Favorite.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    Contract.Favorite._ID + "=" + id, null, null);

            if (cursor3 != null) {
                cursor3.moveToNext();
            //ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            ((ContentResolver) cursor3).delete(Contract.Favorite.CONTENT_URI,Contract.Favorite._ID + "=" + id, null);

            }
    return true;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

> ERROR : java.lang.ClassCastException:
> android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner
> cannot be cast to
> android.content.ContentResolver

Comment: @David Kern, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner
> cannot be cast to
> android.content.ContentResolver

Дословный перевод:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner
> не может быть приведен к 
> android.content.ContentResolver

На какой строчке ошибка? на этой?

```
((ContentResolver)cursor3).delete(Contract.Favorite.CONTENT_URI,Contract.Favorite._ID + "=" + id, null);
```

А с чего вы вообще взяли, что `Cursor cursor3` может быть приведен к типу `ContentResolver`? Где вы видели, что один наследуется от другого?

Comment: Спасибо за коммент :)

Не посоветуете, как можно удалить id из database?

Для удаления я использую этот код, но получаю ERROR: 

>android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
   cr.delete(Contract.Favorite.CONTENT_URI,Contract.Favorite._ID + "=" + id, null);

Comment: Я использовал такой код чтобы удалить весь database

 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
   cr.delete(Contract.Favorite.CONTENT_URI, null, null);

Хотел бы применить к удалению одного id.

Comment: @David Kern, приведенный вами код
    
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver(); cr.delete(Contract.Favorite.CONTENT_URI,Contract.Favorite._ID + "=" + id, null);
    
не может вызвать ошибку 
   
>ERROR : android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    
Она возникает при попытке вычитать из курсора нулевую строку, если курсор не содержит ни одной строки. Всегда внимательно смотрите номера строк.

Comment: спасибо за коммент,
этот код удаляет id, 
но приложение перестаёт работать

 AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
   .getMenuInfo();
        long id = info.id;
       
   ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
   cr.delete(Contract.Favorite.CONTENT_URI,Contract.Favorite._ID + "=" + id, null);

Comment: @David Kern, вы так и не поняли. Стактрейс всегда содержит НОМЕРА СТРОК, в которых возникли ошибки. Ошибка ваша возникает уже после выполнения этих строк. Вы там дальше используете как-то этот ContentResolver cr. Как вы его используете - я не знаю.

Comment: Ок Большое Спасибо :)))))